# Можно ли изменить сообщение в стандартном сообщении браузера при закрытии страницы?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть код, который, по идее, должен бы работать - устанавливать кастомное сообщение.
Но сообщение все равно выводится системное в разных браузерах.

Видел способ на проекте Vue.https://austingil.com/prevent-browser-refresh-url-changes-route-navigation-vue/
Но я не использую в проекте роутинг, так как приложение очень простое из трех табов.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault
      const dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
      e.returnValue = dialogText;
      return dialogText;
    })
```

Comment: Многие браузеры запретили менять это сообщение

Comment: Забудь, это не реал в наши дни